# Use HTML form--> select results as an option to create a table View

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

My objective is to create a table that will change it's view as the user changes the select option in a form.
I'm using Google Visualizations, so after loading the table:

```
var geoData = response.getDataTable();
```

I create a view that is working:

```
var geoView = new google.visualization.DataView(geoData);
geoView.setColumns([0,3,1]);
```

I want this last line to change as the user changes the selection in the following form:

```
<td><select id='query1'onclick="tableCoords(this.value), Remapear()">
    <option value='[0,1]'>Todas</option>
    <option value='[0,3,1]'>P2 - Existenacia de normativas 
        PROVINCIALES que regulan el uso del suelo</option>
    <option value='[0,4,1]'>P3 - Año de la ultima 
        modificacion o promulgacion de la Normativa</option>
    <option value='[0,6,1]'>P4 - Existenacia de 
        Codigo de Uso de Suelo MUNICIPAL</option>
<option value='[0,7,1]'>P5 - Año de la ultima modificacion o 
        promulgacion del Codigo de Uso de Suelo</option>
<option value='[0,3,1]'>P6 - Se encuentra la normativa en 
       el sitio web municipal</option>
<option value='[0,3,1]'>P7 - En el Municipio hay 
        normativa de ZONIFICACION, determinando el uso del suelo</option>
</select></td>
```

I haven't made the function Remapear(), but my guess is the script will have to first be created to perform this task? Can the community assist me with this?